# PayPal subscription upgrade

Tags: php, web-services, api, paypal

My company is providing service, which has few subscription plans with different monthly fee. Everything is working via PayPal recurring payments.

I want to implement upgrade system, so clients could switch to more expensive plan.

For now I found two solutions:

1. Modify current subscription and ask for payment to cover difference in plans to the end of the month (modified subscription will work only from the next month). So basically I need to give my client two different forms to submit to PayPal, which is very bad.
2. Also I could cancel current recurring payment and ask client to subscribe for new. Cancel is possible in the background without any user interaction, he only need to submit new form for new payment.

I like second method more, but it still not very clear for users and I'm looking for better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like option 2 would be the only viable one.

For upgrading have your script put them on a new subscription, then on your script that processes the PayPal reply, have it check to see if the user already has a subscription, if they do, then create a paypal request to cancel the old subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a very old question, I found it while trying to implement this kind of upgrade and I believe might be interesting for other people.

Now, you can upgrade paypal subscription amount programatically. More info here:

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/
- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

However, this has the limitation that you cannot upgrade more than 20% of the current amount for half a year. In my case, and probably many others, the best option is to cancel the current subscription once the new subscription has been approved.

If you need to start charging the subscription next month, it can be easily achieved with the starting date parameters or giving a free trial.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I ran across it while looking for some answers to upgrade/downgrading subscriptions. I wanted to let you know that your links are dead. PayPal shows them as a 404 Error